# Looking for a webhost that offers both Linux and Windows

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

To deploy my .NET web-application I need both Windows (for frontend) and Linux (for database) virtual servers (VPS). What Windows+Linux hoster would you recommend?

Of course, I am not interested in Windows or Linux-specific hosters. Also I found some mix hosters who provides low prices for Linux but high for Windows or vice versa.

Comment: There is usually a difference in price between Linux and Windows. This is at least in part, due to the need to pay for Windows licences which aren't applicable on Linux. Question - Why do you need both at the same provider. Why not just choose the best windows provider and the best linux provider?

Comment: But this difference shouldn't be significant (according to the number of licenses providers buy, I guys they have discounts) and I so hostings where it is so. I want database to be near to frontend (high-speed connection).

Comment: OK, in that case, when choosing a host, be sure to ask them whither the windows and linux boxes will really be sighted close together. I've known some hosts to put different kinds of customers in different locations.

Comment: Thank you! Really good point which I didn't think about

Answer (score 0):

[GoDaddy's virtual dedicated products](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx?ci=9013) have Windows and a couple flavors of Linux available, at equal prices. (Not a recommendation, just pointing out. I've never used GD for hosting.)

Answer (score 0):

I chose http://www.ucvhost.com. I will write my feelings about in some usage time.